# Error on context deadline with docker, what's the meaning?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

What is the meaning and the cause of error "**Context deadline exceeded or context deadline unknown**" when using docker, with docker stack deploy? I see many posts with this error in differents environment and contexts. But i m not able to understand how to avoid this problem.

When i have networks error i know what to do, but not in theses cases.

Comment: It's a fairly generic error, from tools implemented in Go, saying "something took to long".  It frequently means there is a network-configuration problem and not a code error.  Do you have a specific case where this is coming up, ideally including a [mcve]?

Comment: not really, this happens when a do a docker stack deploy within an existing swarm. Not often, but sometimes. What i want to know, if there is a solution or a way that i can put to retry my deploy stack or how to resolve the problem automatically before retrying.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I faced this message when DNS setting was wrong.
Changing the DNS setting to 1.1.1.1 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was my version of Tilt that was causing this to occur (e.g had to upgrade from v0.33.2 --> v0.33.10)